# Using async tokio-postgres concurrently is not `Send`

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, traits

I'm trying to implement asynchronous db access using [tokio-postgres](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/tokio_postgres/) crate. Here is What I tried:

```
use tokio_postgres::{Client, NoTls, Error};

pub struct Database{
    client: Mutex<Client>
}

impl Database {

    pub async fn some_db_operation(&self, /* args */) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let connection = &mut self.client.lock().expect("Mutex was poisoned");
        let transaction = &mut connection.transaction().await?;
        //executing some queries
        Ok(())
    }

}
```

The problem is that I want to access the database as a part of incoming http-request handling using [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) and therefore everything should be `Send`. I got the following error:

```
  --> src/db.rs:27:32
   |
26 |         let connection = &mut self.client.lock().expect("Mutex was poisoned");
   |                               ----------------------------------------------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, tokio_postgres::client::Client>` which is not `Send`
27 |         let transaction = &mut connection.transaction().await?;
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `self.client.lock().expect("Mutex was poisoned")` maybe used later
```

Is there a workaround to make it `Send`?

There was no such a problem with a synchronous client.

Comment: Maybe you should use [Tokio's `Mutex`](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html) whose guard [appears to be `Send`](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-Send).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MutexGuard` (the result of calling `lock()` on a `Mutex`) is not `Send`. [The relevant part in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-Send) is the manual implementation of `!Send` ("not `Send`").

I would strongly suggest to look into some sort of connection pooling, perhaps with [deadpool_postgres](https://docs.rs/deadpool-postgres/0.5.6/deadpool_postgres/) which is built around `tokio-postgres`. Using a single client behind a mutex will likely tank your async performance anyway.

Comment: Do you know why doesn't compiler compain in a synchronous case?

Comment: @SomeName The compiler does not complain in the synchronous case because, without using `await`, there is no chance for your code to be resumed on a different thread than it started on. The performance hit from using a single client behind a mutex is however also present in the synchronous code, so definitely go for a connection pool

Comment: I can't say exactly without seeing the code of that version. However, if you did not use threads, there was likely nothing that could require `Send` there. However in async version, your future needs to implement `Send` since, as far as I know, Tokio uses a multi-threaded executor, meaning that your future could get suspended in one thread and resumed in another.